# Fitnesse Compare Statement

Tags: fitnesse

Is this possible to compare two strings in fitness:

```
!define Str {ABC}
```

that

```
${= ${Str} == ABC =}
```

will return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the equality operator is not supported in FitNesse expressions.